# How to create a Gradient in Spritekit?

Tags: sprite-kit

Is there any possible way to create a gradient filled box in SpriteKit? I've tried filling a shape node with that but it notes that only solid colors work with skshapenode.

Comment: I'm back.. and found this: https://gist.github.com/Tantas/7fc01803d6b559da48d6

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894493/making-a-skscenes-background-transparent-not-working-is-this-a-bug/24494346#24494346

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with current `SKShapeNode`, which barely handles its basic features currently. A good approach if you don't want to use pre-existing sprite gradient images would be to create an `SKTexture` from applying a `CIFilter` (like maybe `CILinearGradient` in this case) to a basic box image, and then create the `SKSpriteNode` from that `SKTexture`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution. (Note, I am using Rubymotion, a Ruby binding for Objective-C / iOS, however the logic is exactly the same. If someone wants to edit this and put the Objective-C equivalent, go ahead

```rb
size = CGSizeMake(50,50)
scale = options[:scale] || UIScreen.mainScreen.scale
opaque = options.fetch(:opaque, false)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, opaque, scale)
context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

gradient = CAGradientLayer.layer
gradient.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)
gradient.colors = [SKColor.blackColor.CGColor,SKColor.whiteColor.CGColor]
gradient.renderInContext(context)

image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

texture = SKTexture.textureWithCGImage(image.CGImage)
node = SKSpriteNode.alloc.initWithTexture(texture)
```

Comment: Thanks but this won't work for OSX:Sprite Kit. It is limited to iOS.

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions does not exist.

Comment: I"m using Rubymotion, and would love to see the ruby version of this code.

Answer (score 4):

OK here is something I am using now. I based it on AwDogsGo2Heaven's solution, however adapted for Mac. Would be sweet with one fully compatible solution. I am far from sure how to create contexts. But seems to work. Also I am unsure about the scale. Running on retina mac and non retina mac and can't see any problems but the context is created using scale 2 so might be overkill for non retina macs. I put this in a category on SKTexture.

In order use it, just call `+(SKTexture*)gradientWithSize:(const CGSize)SIZE colors:(NSArray*)colors`.

**Edit:** Updated code and more discussion here: [Gradient texture has wrong scale on retina Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538624/gradient-texture-has-wrong-scale-on-retina-mac?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Matt's answer is correct, but I have be unable to add a gradient as yet. This is my currrent attempt, if someone knows how to make it work, please update for thread.

Here is the [Core Image Ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIQRCodeGenerator)

```
CIFilter *gradientFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CILinearGradient"];
//[gradientFilter setDefaults];
CIColor *startColor = [CIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
CIColor *endColor = [CIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
CIVector *startVector = [CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0];
CIVector *endVector = [CIVector vectorWithX:0.21 Y:0.31];
[gradientFilter setValue:startVector forKey:@"inputPoint0"];
[gradientFilter setValue:endVector forKey:@"inputPoint1"];
[gradientFilter setValue:startColor forKey:@"inputColor0"];
[gradientFilter setValue:endColor forKey:@"inputColor1"];

SKEffectNode *effectNode = [SKEffectNode node];
effectNode.filter = gradientFilter;
effectNode.shouldEnableEffects = YES;

[self addChild:effectNode];
//effectNode.position = CGPointMake(200, 200);
```

Another good way to test your filters, is download the demo app **CIFunHouse** from WWDC 2013.

Comment: I was able to create a gradient us CAGradientLayer and creating an UIImage context, rendering that layer on the the context, and creating a texture from the resulting UIImage, it was fast, and I didn't experience any slow down (But I only needed to create one for a button).

Comment: I added the answer above.

Comment: Still it only works for iOS and this question is not limited to iOS.

Comment: Also it crashes on the first line with tvOS. *Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<CILinearGradient 0x15ddc03a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key inputImage.'*

Comment: Ok I'll try to work on it. The usage is not correct.

Comment: Now. crashed with inputImage error message undefined key etc etc on iOS 14 too.