# Use UIview subview with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scene, game-development

So I am working on a simple SpriteKit ball and obstacle game. I have the zposition for the nodes set to 2 ( can be 1 but I set it to 2 to make sure it doesn’t interfere with anything else)

I am trying to add a background to it but instead of an image my I want to use a UIview as the background for my game.   How should I use a uiview as a background for a SpriteKit scene. ?

The uiview I’m using is called [**Pastel**](https://github.com/cruisediary/Pastel). It’s a library that allows you to create animated gradient backgrounds like the Instagram app login screen. 
 I tried adjusting the position at

### And I’ve even used the sendabove and sendbelow methods but they don’t work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Gradient in Spritekit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254957/how-to-create-a-gradient-in-spritekit)

Answer (score 0):

In order for `UIView` with your background which is under `SKView` to become visible, you must set the `allowsTransparency` property of your `SKView` to true.

**Edit:**

you also need to set the SKView and the SKScene background color to clear – (thanks to Knight0fDragon)

Comment: I tried the allowed transparency property but it still doesnt work.

Comment: it is more complicated than that,  you also need to set the SKView and the SKScene background color to clear