# Dimming SKScene by adding SKScene/SKView or UIView on top not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, uikit

I'm coding a game where when the user loses I want there to be a reset button in the middle of the screen with the rest of it dimmed out. For some reason I can't get transparency to work. I've looked up solutions but couldn't get it to work with mine (there are too many variables that aren't defined) and I can't comment because I don't have enough rep:

[Making a SKScene's background transparent not working... is this a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894493/making-a-skscenes-background-transparent-not-working-is-this-a-bug)

I have a gamescene that extends SKScene where I add all of my SKNodes to a mainView node. I've tried setting the transparency to YES and adding a new skscene with clearColor on top of it but it just shows a black screen:

```
SKView *dimView = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
[self.view addSubview:dimView];
[dimView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[dimView setAllowsTransparency:YES];
```

I know I'm doing something wrong I just don't know what it is. Can anyone pinpoint my mistake?

Update:

I've also tried this and it doesn't work either, also black screen:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
//create a new view with the same size
UIView* coverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];
// change the background color to black and the opacity to 0.6
coverView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];
// add this new view to your main view
[self.view addSubview:coverView];
```

Update 2:

I've edited the first code set to try to overlay the skview with another skview whose transparency is set to true and color is set to clear color. This way I just get a gray screen. I've been at this for a while and really can't seem to figure out why this isn't working. Any help would be appreciated.

Update 3:

So I think the correct implementation of overlaying a view with another is like so but even with this it still shows a completely black screen:

```
    CGRect screenFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    SKView *dimView = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:screenFrame];
    SKScene *currentScene = [[SKScene alloc]initWithSize:dimView.bounds.size];
    [self.view addSubview:dimView];
    [currentScene setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f]];
    [dimView setAllowsTransparency:YES];
    [dimView presentScene:currentScene];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FINIALLY FIGURED IT OUT! My problem was that I had my code in the update method and wasn't checking to see if it was already added. I was adding multiple views every iteration of the update loop all with an opacity of .5 which caused it to seem black.

Answer (score 0):

According to overview section of the [SKScene Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/index.html):

> An SKScene object represents a scene of content in Sprite Kit. A scene
>   is the root node in a tree of Sprite Kit nodes (SKNode). These nodes
>   provide content that the scene animates and renders for display. To
>   display a scene, you present it from an SKView object.

You do not nest `SKScene` 's. You can't have two scenes running at the same time (only transitioning between them).

If you want to "overlaying" two scenes you always have to switch from using a transition.

An alternative could be a GitHub project to customize transition scene with shaders called [SpriteKitShaderTransitionExample](https://github.com/dbotha/SpriteKitShaderTransitionExample)

As you can see from the sources below, it's extended the `SKScene` to integrate the shader.

**Source**:

```
//private let totalAnimationDuration = 1.0
private let kNodeNameTransitionShaderNode = "kNodeNameTransitionShaderNode"
private let kNodeNameFadeColourOverlay = "kNodeNameFadeColourOverlay"
private var presentationStartTime: CFTimeInterval = -1
private var shaderChoice = -1

extension SKScene {
    private var transitionShader: SKShader? {
        get {
            if let shaderContainerNode = self.childNodeWithName(kNodeNameTransitionShaderNode) as? SKSpriteNode {
                return shaderContainerNode.shader
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
    private func createShader(shaderName: String, transitionDuration: NSTimeInterval) -> SKShader {
        var shader = SKShader(fileNamed:shaderName)
        var u_size = SKUniform(name: "u_size", floatVector3: GLKVector3Make(Float(UIScreen.mainScreen().scale * size.width), Float(UIScreen.mainScreen().scale * size.height), Float(0)))
        var u_fill_colour = SKUniform(name: "u_fill_colour", floatVector4: GLKVector4Make(131.0 / 255.0, 149.0 / 255.0, 255.0 / 255.0, 1.0))
        var u_border_colour = SKUniform(name: "u_border_colour", floatVector4: GLKVector4Make(104.0 / 255.0, 119.0 / 255.0, 204.0 / 255.0, 1.0))
        var u_total_animation_duration = SKUniform(name: "u_total_animation_duration", float: Float(transitionDuration))
        var u_elapsed_time = SKUniform(name: "u_elapsed_time", float: Float(0))
        shader.uniforms = [u_size, u_fill_colour, u_border_colour, u_total_animation_duration, u_elapsed_time]
        return shader
    }
    func presentScene(scene: SKScene?, shaderName: String, transitionDuration: NSTimeInterval) {
        // Create shader and add it to the scene
        var shaderContainer = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "dummy")
        shaderContainer.name = kNodeNameTransitionShaderNode
        shaderContainer.zPosition = 9999 // something arbitrarily large to ensure it's in the foreground
        shaderContainer.position = CGPointMake(size.width / 2, size.height / 2)
        shaderContainer.size = CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height)
        shaderContainer.shader = createShader(shaderName, transitionDuration:transitionDuration)
        self.addChild(shaderContainer)
        // remove the shader from the scene after its animation has completed.
        let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(transitionDuration * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            var fadeOverlay = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height))
            fadeOverlay.name = kNodeNameFadeColourOverlay
            fadeOverlay.fillColor = SKColor(red: 131.0 / 255.0, green: 149.0 / 255.0, blue: 255.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            fadeOverlay.zPosition = shaderContainer.zPosition
            scene!.addChild(fadeOverlay)
            self.view!.presentScene(scene)
        })
        // Reset the time presentScene was called so that the elapsed time from now can
        // be calculated in updateShaderTransitions(currentTime:)
        presentationStartTime = -1
    }
    func updateShaderTransition(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        if let shader = self.transitionShader {
            let elapsedTime = shader.uniformNamed("u_elapsed_time")!
            if (presentationStartTime < 0) {
                presentationStartTime = currentTime
            }
            elapsedTime.floatValue = Float(currentTime - presentationStartTime)
        }
    }
    // this function is called by the scene being transitioned to when it's ready to have the view faded in to the scene i.e. loading is complete, etc.
    func completeShaderTransition() {
        if let fadeOverlay = self.childNodeWithName(kNodeNameFadeColourOverlay) {
            fadeOverlay.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(0, duration: 0.3), SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: I don't necessarily want to overlay two scenes, what I actually want is to overlay a view with another view where the view on top is a black color with a .5-.6 opacity. This is to give the background a dimmed out effect when the user loses the game. With the code above I wasn't able to achieve this as the overlaying scene is always opaque.

Comment: I don't understand you, what do you mean? You must distinguish UIKit from Sprite-kit, so what are you actually get?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've attempted to overlay my SKScene with a  different SKView but this doesn't seem to work, it isn't transparent. I've also attempted to overlay my SKScene with a UIView but this also isn't transparent. What I want is for my SKScene nodes to be visible through another view or scene, I don't really care which. The effect I'm looking for is a dimmed effect for my originial scene.